# How to find and replace a string with a particular set of conditions in bash

Tags: bash, sed, replace, scripting

I have a folder which contains another set of folders,each with a .csv file on which the changes need to be made.

I want to look for a particular string and replace it

Example of my csv file is

XX,1,2,3,4,AA,BB,5,6...

YY,5,6,7,5,CC,DD,9,10...

I wish to replace AA(6th location) with "aa,bb,cc" FOR ONLY those lines whose first word is XX
I wish to replace CC(6th location if I used delimiter, same as the previous line) with "cc,dd,ee" FOR ONLY those lines whose first word is YY

How to I make a recursive search through all folders, and search for these strings only in the .csv file and make these changes.

```
#!/bin/bash
file=test1.txt
IFS=$','
for i in `cat $file`
do
  echo "the name of the file I am going to is"
  echo "$i"
#add logic to look for "line beginning with XX and replace the 6th word in that line      
sed -e 's/^XX.\{0\}/replacedAB/' $i
done
```

test1.txt contains the path to the .csv file.

I am using /bin/bash and my version is 4.1.2(1)

Is there any way we can use sed or read command to replace a string in a line with begins with XX?

Comment: what have you tried? We can't help improve your knowledge of scripting if we don't know what your current approach to the problem is. What you describe can be solved with `sed` or `awk` scripts. You might want to check the Tutorials at http://grymoire.com/Unix . Good luck.

Comment: Could you help me kickstart this with fetching the line that has XX and replace the string in that line

Comment: This is probably too specific to work in any real scenario, but `sed s/XX/replacement/`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply:) I do understand the use of sed but I do not understand how to  replace a string in the line that contains "XX" and not the string "XX" itself

Comment: kick : http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-27

Comment: can you help me out with this?

Comment: `awk` is probably the best tool for this, since it's good with data in tables.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is you use `grep` initially to build the "detect" expression. If you output to the screen or specify `--color=always` you can see the matching expression hilighted in the output.

Then add grouping brackets round the bits of the detect expression you want to keep, and convert that into a `sed` to keep each of the bits you want and inject replacements for the bits you don't want.

That's how.